# Days distinction between mars and earth orbiting

Tags: algorithms

Assuming that Earth orbits the Sun over a period of $365$ Earth days, and
Mars orbits the Sun over a period of $687$ Earth days.

The earth orbit starts at Day $0$ and continues to Day $364$
and starts over at Day $0$.

Mars orbit is similar but is on a $687$-day time-scale instead.

How can I determine how long it will take until both planets are on day $0$ of their orbits at the same time?

Let me give you an example:
If Earth is on Day $364$ and if Mars is on Day $686$, the smallest number of days till the two planets will both be on day $0$ of their orbit is $1$.

However, if Earth is at Day $0$ and Mars at Day $1$, the smallest number of days till the two planets will both be on day $0$ of their orbit is $239075$.

Comment: Look up the Chinese Remainder theorem and the Euclidean algorithm.

Comment: 0 Mod(365) => 0, I dont know if the problem can be solved using modules

Comment: You are looking for a solution to $n\equiv 0 \pmod{365}, n \equiv 1 \pmod {687}$  The Chinese Remainder theorem guarantees a solution and tells yo the solutions recur every $365\cdot 687$ days  The Euclidean algorithm gives you a process to find the solution.  There are examples on this site or you can see the Wikipedia pages

Comment: Here is what I tried: The Chinese Remainder theorem => B1X1C1 + B2X2C2 => B1 = 250755/365 = 687, B2 = 250755/687 = 365. To get the X1 and X2, 687X1 = 1mod 365 = X1 = 322 and 365X2 = 1mod 687 X2 = 365. The C1 and C2 is 0,1.  => 687 x 322 x 0 + 365 x  365 x 1 = 133225. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Comments with lengthy unformatted calculations are practically unreadable. The thing to do is to edit the question and add the calculations there, using MathJax formatting. https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to solve $365k\equiv 1 \pmod {687}$, which is solved by $k\equiv 32 \pmod {687}$.  This means $365\cdot 32=11680$ is what you seek.

Comment: How did you get k=32? and also shouldn't the answer be 239075?

Comment: I just asked [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=inverse+of+365+modulo+687).  You can check that $11680$ works easily, just divide $\frac {11680}{687}$ and note that the remainder is $1$.  $239075 \equiv -1 \equiv 686 \pmod {687}$ has the wrong sign.